# Show random results 50% of the time, other 50% show another result?

Tags: javascript, php

Currently I am trying to display data in **50 / 50** portions using either Javascript or PHP and having a tough time understanding how to achieve this.

When a user views the page, I want there to be a 50% chance that they see an alert, another 50% chance that the alert is not there.

```
<div class="alert">HELLO! Please consider signing up for our website.</div>
```

Comment: Google is your friend. Look for "how to create a random number" - some rand() Math.rand() function - the rest ist pretty much just printing the element - straight forward.

Answer (score 5):

Just generate a random number between `0` and `1` and check whether it is above `0.5`.

In JavaScript you can generate a random number between `0` and `1` using [`Math.random()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Math/random). Comparing that number to `0.5` can be done using the ["greater than" `>` operator](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Operators/Comparison_Operators#Greater_than_operator).

---

Put these two together into a little helper function ...

```
function shouldShowAlert() {
  return Math.random() > 0.5
}
```

... call and use it inside an `if` ...

```
if (shouldShowAlert()) {
  // Show your alert
}
```

... and you've solved your problem.

Answer (score 1):

In PHP, because why not. This will get you started a bit of the way:

```
$rand = rand(1,2);

if ($rand == 1) {
    echo '<div class="alert">HELLO! Please consider signing up for our website.</div>'
}
```

How this works - when the user visits your page, `rand()` will generate a number, either 1 or 2 based on the parameters we used (1,2). The IF statement will then check if the assigned variable `$rand` is a 1, if so, it shows the message. If not, no message is shown.